# Why rasterizing objects in Illustrator causes them to be pixelated

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pixelation, rasterization

I am having a sudden problem with my vectors after being rasterized within Illustrator. The rasterized image becomes pixelated. If anyone might have an idea as to what might have happened all of a sudden, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Thank you and here are some reference screenshots of what I mean.

[image: before rasterizing]

[image: after rasterizing]

Comment: The problem specifically is that this happens at 100% zoom. It wasn't happening before so I am not sure what I did t change it.

Comment: 1. Are you super sure this is the actual size (100% zoom)? This looks like a raster image that's been upsized after rasterization... or zoomed in. 2. Try different rasterization options.

Comment: yeah you were right, I was working too small. I scaled up the vector before rasterizing it and it worked. The issue I was having when I was working too small was that after image tracing the pixelated raster, the pixelation became part of the newly image traced vector. Scaling up the vector before rasterizing it makes it smoother. 

I shouldn't stay up so late next time. 

Thank you.

Comment: @techtonio why are you rasterizing your vectors just to trace them again? Regardless, you don't need to scale the vector, just rasterize at a higher resolution as I said in my answer

Answer (score 3):

Rasterization turns your vector artwork in to a raster image. A raster image is made up of pixels. Ergo pixelation. There's no way around that.

Either your Illustrator document is too small (Illustrator defaults to 1pt = 1px, i.e 72PPI) or you chose too low a resolution in the rasterize dialog.

To get a higher resolution image (i.e less pixelation), simply choose a higher resolution in the rasterize dialog:

[image]